# jQuery jTable selecting rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

i have a jTable and i need to select all rows so i could later give information to AJAX and send data to controller for proccessing.

My problem is that i can't get it working. Here is the JS code so far.

```
 $('#saveButton').click(function(){ 
        $('#UserTable').jtable("selectRows"); // I think here is the problem
        var $selectedRows = $('#smsUserTable').jtable('selectedRows');
        $selectedRows.each(function () {
            var record = $(this).data('record');
            var userId = record.userId;
            console.log(userId);
        });
      });
```

I get Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClass' of undefined error all the time.

Maybe i am using selectRows method wrong. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think this code is the problem as you are not calling `addClass` anywhere. That error normally comes when you're trying to use a jQuery function on a native DOM object.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is solution?

```
$('#UserTable .jtable-data-row').each(function () {
            $(this).addClass('jtable-row-selected');
            $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
        });
```

This select all visible rows in table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code to get all table recods data in json string:

```
/* Select all Records */
$('#your_table .jtable-data-row').each(function () {
    $(this).addClass('jtable-row-selected');
    $(this).addClass('ui-state-highlight');
});
/* Read each record and add it to json */
var $selectedRows = $('#your_table').jtable('selectedRows'),records = [];
$selectedRows.each(function () {
    var record = $(this).data('record');
    records.push(record);
});
var josn_data = JSON.stringify(records);
```